# Как в телеграмм боте сделать функцию, которая будет отправлять фото в чат без предварительного сообщения от пользователя?

Tags: python, циклы, telebot

Только начал изучать создание ботов, не могу найти как сделать, чтоб бот отправлял рандомное фото (карточки по английскому языку), после этого пользователь вводит ответ и бот отправляет новое фото. Чтоб этот процесс шел циклом?

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def answer(message):
    if message.text == photo.name:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Верно')
        photo1 = open('eng/' + random.choice(os.listdir('eng')), 'rb')
        bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo1)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Следующее слово на английском?')
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Не верно')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, answer)
```

После вывода сообщения "Верно", отправлялось новое фото

Answer (score 0):

Важно - отправить сообщение, если пользовать ни разу не отправил сообщение боту невозможно. То есть он должен хотя бы кнопку старт нажать стандартную.

После этого же ты можешь спамить сообщениями сколько хочешь. Чтобы отправить сообщение без обработчика, тебе сперва нужно сохранить id чатов (chat_id = message.chat.id), в базу или файл, например. После просто используешь этот id в любом место программы, сообщение отправится и без действий пользователя

```
bot.send_message(chat_id, 'что угодно')
```